# How to dynamically provide the fieldname when creating an Object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I am trying to dynamically add the field name and value in the javascript object using es6 structuring. The problem is its not using the value just the fieldName

```
updateValue(event){

        let varName = event.target.dataset.field;

        this.realFormData = {...this.realFormData , varName : event.detail.value};
        console.log( this.realFormData); 
    }
```

Console.log OP: `{somefield:"someValue" , varname : "somevalue"}`

As you can see, it has used field as varName and not the value of varName

How to bind value of `varName` instead of its string?

Comment: Wrap your object's key with third bracket, like this {[varname]: "somevalue""}

Comment: Try using [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this :

```
this.realFormData = {...this.realFormData , [varName] : event.detail.value};
```